# C++ if statements using strings not working as intended

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have searched for this error but noone seems to be having the same problem as me. I am trying to make a basic text based RPG game in C++ to learn, and I want the user to be able to type what they want to do, for example if they type `ATTACK` they will attack the monster, but my if statement:

```
if((current_move == "ATTACK") || (current_move == "attack"))
```

returns false!

Here is the full function below:

```
while(monster_health > 0)
    {
        std::cin >> current_move;
        std::cout << current_move;
        if((current_move == "ATTACK") || (current_move == "attack"))
        {
            std::cout << "You attacked the monster!\n";

            double damage = return_level(xp) * 1.2;

            std::cout << "You did " << damage << " damage!\n";

            monster_health -= damage;
            if(monster_health < 0)
            {
                monster_health = 0;
                break_out = true;
            }
        }
        else if(current_move == "FLEE")
        {
            std::cout << "You ran away...\n";
            break_out = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, I didn't understand, what will you do? ATTACK or FLEE?\n";
        }
    }
```

I just keep getting "Sorry, I didn't understand" message;

Please let me know of any other errors or bad practises as I've only just started learning :)

Comment: Can you edit in the declaration of `current_move`? Knowing what the type is is important.

Comment: +1 @j883376.  Dollars to doughnuts, they're C strings.

Comment: It's declared above: char current_move [20];

Comment: @AdamTester There you go.

Comment: If you switch to using `std::string` you can simplify the comparisons by converting the string to lower case with something like `std::transform(current_move.begin(), current_move.end(), current_move.begin(), ::tolower);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's the type of `current_move`? If it's `char*` (or `char[]`), you are comparing pointers, not strings. Better use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) for `current_move`, then the comparison with `==` will work intuitively.

You need to add `#include <string>`. (In MSVC certain parts of strings also work without that, but it's nonstandard and leads to errors e.g. when passing strings to `cout`).

Comment: Thinking the same thing, Oberon, because if that code was using the string class, the if statement should be evaluating true. Can't see any other error.

Comment: When I do this I get errors like: Error 1 error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @AdamTester don't forget to `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a C string (`char[]`), you need to use `strcmp()` to compare it. If the two strings are equivalent, it will return 0.

`if (strcmp(current_move, "ATTACK") == 0)` will return `true` if they match.

Comment: and what does strcmp return when it is true?

Comment: Probably actually needs to use strcmpi, which is a case Insensitive compare, then just do if (strcmpi(current_move, "ATTACK") == 0), which will return 0 when current_move is "attack", "AtTaCk" or "aTaCk" or ..., so there will then be no need to compare against ALL CAPS or all lower (or any other permutation of CaPs that are just as valid)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do current_move==string("attack") otherwise you will be comparing pointers. String operator == or strncmp, either one or the other...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are comparing C strings. When you do `==` on them, you are comparing the pointer of the two, which in this code is useless to do.

My suggestion would be to just change the type of `current_move` to `std::string` and it will just work. Then you will be comparing the contents, not the pointers.